# character encoding when translating Django and pushing to bitbucket

Tags: django, linux, pycharm

Using Linux Fedora, and PyCharm both English versions

1, I am in the process of translating the content using the i18n built-in Django.
When I write python manage.py compilemessages I get:

```
'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u201c' in position 5: ordinal not in range(256)
This '\u20ic' refers to Double quotes. The file to translate has double quotes.
```

2. When I push to bitbucket, even though it does push it, I get this message

`xkbcommon: ERROR: /usr/share/X11/locale/iso8859-1/Compose:49:29: string literal is not a valid UTF-8 string` 
I went to check the file encodings in PyCharm and was disgusted to see that it was not UTF-8 but some ascii variant. I changed to UTF-8 but nothing happened, I can't compile the messages in the .po file

This is a snippet of the Django file that because it has double quotes, it can't be compiled

```
#: scaffoldapp/templates/index.html:279
msgid "Life is life."
msgstr "la vida es la vida"

#: templates/account/account_inactive.html:5
#: templates/account/account_inactive.html:8
msgid "Account Inactive"
msgstr ""
```

UPDATE

I first wrote:
python manage.py makemessages -l 'es'
and a folder locale was created in the root directory with another folder es and another one LC_MESSAGES.
inside this one there is a default file called django.po

A snippet in this file is:

```
#. Translators: "letters" means latin letters: a-z and A-Z.
#: venv9Abril/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/validators.py:256
msgid ""
"Enter a valid “slug” consisting of letters, numbers, underscores or hyphens."
msgstr ""
```

I do see the right and left double quotes as in here, but even if I get rid of all of them, the error continues. It is as if the error were referring to another file, but the compilemessages refers to po files only.

UPDATE 2:

I took the default file django.po and removed ALL lines except a few harmless lines. It still gives the error. This clearly says the python manage.py compilemessages is referring to another file. It must be some configuratio somewhere.

```
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2023-08-26 19:17+0000\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"Language: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);\n"

#: estate/settings.py:125
msgid "English"
msgstr "Ingles"
```

UPDATE 3.

Three times I have been able to make it work, yet I can't still figure out exactly why or how. Here is my approach.
a) First, the error was not in the po files, that is for certain 100% as even empty they gave the error.
b) The error seems to be related, linked to the default LANGUAGE_CODE in the settings.py  The thing is that I have changed many times to en and then to es, and I made no progress. Then I tried again changing it to the es (which is Spanish, and therefore latin-1 codec and then all of a sudden it built me all of the compile files for all of the languages.

Comment: It is not because it has double quotes, it is because the quotes are not, well unicode quotes, but `“`. You should search for `“` (ad probably the counterquotes as well), and then replace these by `"`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not because it has double quotes, it is because the quotes are not, well unicode quotes, but `“`. You should search for `“` (ad probably the counterquotes as well), and then replace these by `"`.

For example with sed you can use:

```
sed -E -i 's/“/"/g' *.mo
```

likely, the same should be done for `201d` (`”`):

```
sed -E -i 's/”/"/g' *.mo
```

Comment: @Alvar: can you share the part with the slug (in the `.mo` file) by editing the question?

Comment: yes, I will, note that it is a po file, not mo, and I modified that  as it has not been compiled yet, it is in the compilation that fails, I will include the snippet in the update above